# Delphi Executing command line command

Tags: delphi, command-line, shellexecute

I am trying to run a command-line command from inside my Delphi application.

```
ShellExecute(Form1.Handle, 
             'open', 
             'cmd.exe',
             'icacls "C:\ProgramData\My Program\File" /grant Users:F',
             nil,
             SW_NORMAL);
```

Note: The command its self works perfectly.

However when I run this code in Delphi I get the command window popping up but the command I want to execute doesn't run or even appear in the command window.

Any idea as to what I am missing?

Comment: cacls is not DOS command

Comment: And not even "dir" is. DOS is not a part of a modern Windows system. "dir" is a command-line command, or system command, though.

Comment: Also, you should use `SW_SHOWNORMAL`.

Comment: Andreas: that depends if you call dir within cmd.exe or command.com. Within command.com it runs afaik within a dos kernel context. But indeed, in general not everything textmode is dos. Dos is something else.

Comment: @Marco: When I wrote "a **modern** Windows system", I was -- of course -- excluding Windows 9x. Windows NT-based systems, such as Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7 do not have a command.com. (At least not the two last ones -- I do not really remember the two first, but they aren't very modern either.)

Comment: actually mixing up `dir` and `cacls` is really wrong too :-P (OP dont need command processor at all)

Comment: True. He should probably just `ShellExecute` it (what is `icacls` by the way?).

Comment: @user205376: the command is icacls and not cacls
@Andres Rejbrand: it's a cmdline tool to set permissions.

Comment: The Delphi way to work with permissions would be to use the Jedi Windows Security Library aka Jwscl

Comment: Well, it would be far better off not to go screwing around with permissions in ProgramData and follow the platform guidelines!

Comment: icacls.exe is a newer version of the command line executable tool used to work with NTFS file permission. It supersedes the older cacls.exe and xcacls.exe utilities, but it is available only from Windows 2003 SP2 and Vista onwards, IIRC.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: 32 bit versions of Vista/2008/2003/XP still have command.com and I think win7 32 bit has it as well.

Comment: @Remko: Really? I ran 32-bit Vista two years ago, but do not remember seeing any command.com.

Comment: @Heffernan: what are the platform guidelines for windows 7 when it comes to storing a licensing file? I didn't want it in the registry since I want it global to all users and not all will have access to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. I wanted it outside of the program folder in an attempt to avoid tampering with the file. @Everyone: Thank you

Comment: @Remko: thank you, Captain Obvious! :-P Anyway, license related stuff is for premium consulting.

Comment: @Tim: even that is a license file, why those very high permission? Every logged-on user has read permission of application keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. Same as well in <programdata>. If it is global to all user then a user with adequate permission should store it. Otherwise the license key should be user-specific. As I often say, Window is not unsecure. It's programmers and users making it so. You should adopt a "least privileges needed" policy, not a "free for all" one. It could backfire...

Comment: Andreas Rejbrand: afaik 32-bit versions still have command.com. I'm sure about w2000 and XP. 64-bit versions can't run 16-bit code.

Comment: @lsdandon: I appreciate the facts your provide, though not so much your HO ;). The original reason I wanted the licensing file to have write permission was to store the last login datetime so I could prevent the user from resetting the system time to break my applications 30 day demo mode. But today I have made tweaks to the program and have it now that even if the file is removed the program will recognize this as a possible act of piracy. This being as it is I now see no reason not to have it just in the program directory with the exe.

Comment: @Tim: you were not setting "write" ("M", modify) permission. You were setting "full control" ("F") permission. Again, it looks you don't know the difference. If the file is shared across users, it is even more important to avoid one user could damage a file that will be used by another. You also changed permission on a file because "not all have access to HKLM", but you can also set permissions on registry keys (although, as with files and directories, you should be very careful to change permissions on them). Allowing unrestricted write access to <program files> is bad as well.

Comment: @ldsandon: I very much appreciate you taking the time to aid me in this matter. I have not worked with setting permissions since college and this quick test code has already been changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command string needs something in front of it.

/c - will cause it to run

/k - will cause it to run and not disappear when done

Answer (score 2):

You have no need to create a shell to run such a command. It is console executable, and you can run it directly with CreateProcess(). Invoking a shell just mean to invoke an executable (cmd.exe) and have it invoke the other more or less the same way you would have invoked it directly. You just spend time creating two processes instead of one. IMHO that's a bad programing practice, and just shows the caller has not a clue on how Windows works ;)

Answer (score 2):

Which OS are you using? I'm pretty sure a command like this requires elevation on any Windows platform after XP.

Here's the code I use for elevating a process under Vista/Windows 7

```
uses
  Windows, ShellAPI, Registry;

type
  TExecuteFileOption = (
    eoHide,
    eoWait,
    eoElevate
  );
  TExecuteFileOptions = set of TExecuteFileOption;

...

function IsUACActive: Boolean;
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Result := FALSE;

  if CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
  begin
    Result := FALSE;

    Reg := TRegistry.Create;
    try
      Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

      if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System') then
      begin
        if (Reg.ValueExists('EnableLUA')) and (Reg.ReadBool('EnableLUA')) then
          Result := TRUE;
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(Reg);
    end;
  end;
end;

function ExecuteFile(Handle: HWND; const Filename, Paramaters: String; Options: TExecuteFileOptions): Integer;
var
  ShellExecuteInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  ExitCode: DWORD;
begin
  Result := -1;

  ZeroMemory(@ShellExecuteInfo, SizeOf(ShellExecuteInfo));
  ShellExecuteInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
  ShellExecuteInfo.Wnd := Handle;
  ShellExecuteInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;

  if (eoElevate in Options) and (IsUACActive) then
    ShellExecuteInfo.lpVerb := PChar('runas');

  ShellExecuteInfo.lpFile := PChar(Filename);

  if Paramaters <> '' then
    ShellExecuteInfo.lpParameters := PChar(Paramaters);

  // Show or hide the window
  if eoHide in Options then
    ShellExecuteInfo.nShow := SW_HIDE
  else
    ShellExecuteInfo.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;

  if ShellExecuteEx(@ShellExecuteInfo) then
    Result := 0;

  if (Result = 0) and (eoWait in Options) then
  begin
    GetExitCodeProcess(ShellExecuteInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);

    while (ExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE) and
          (not Application.Terminated) do
    begin
      sleep(50);

      GetExitCodeProcess(ShellExecuteInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);
    end;

    Result := ExitCode;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi there did you verify if post XP OSes needed admin privs to run with commnad line arguments? Just curious as my users may not have logged into an Admin account.